# Для чего компилятор автоматически определяет конструктор по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

При написании своего класса, если я явно не определяю конструктор, то компилятор генерирует его сам. Но возникает вопрос - для чего? Я предположил, что он должен быть всегда, что бы не было никаких ошибок, но я могу сделать так: `Constructor() = delete;` и класс будет без конструкторов вообще, за исключением конструктора копирования и возможно других. Так для чего тогда компилятор его определяет, если можно и без него обойтись?

Comment: Ну а как создать объект? Если нет ни одного конструктора? Как гарантировать его (объекта) корректное состояние?

Comment: @Harry, я могу ошибаться, но мы же можем удалить все конструкторы (поправьте меня если это не так) и все будет хорошо, разве нет?

Comment: рекомендую почитать "дизайн и эволюция с++" от Страуструпа. И многие подобные вопросы просто отпадут сами собой.

Comment: https://ideone.com/vqyiLJ

Comment: Для удобства, чтобы не писать вручную для всех классов одно и то-же. Со смыслом : сконструировать объект по-умолчанию с элементами, сконструированными по-умолчанию.

Answer (score -1):

Что делает **компилятор**:

- Если в классе нет явных конструкторов и имеются только члены POD типов или структуры содержащие только POD и без явных конструкторов то компилятор создает неявный конструктор по умолчанию **который инициализирует всю структуру нулями**. Этот конструктор будет вызываться только если создаваемый объект имеет явный инициализатор. Это действие можно отменить `delete`.
- Если у класса нет конструктора (явного и неявного) и смесь членов POD и не-POD (т.е классов с конструкторами), то неявный конструктор по умолчанию создается и вызывается в любом случае, но вызывает конструкторы по умолчанию только у не-POD членов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123951/discussion-on-answer-by-noskill------).